# CMS for anonymous interaction

Tags: content-management-system, uploader

I need a CMS that allow me to interact with people anonymousely... The site will present some video, some picture... but i need to :

Let ANYBODY without registering send video, post and picture. those media will fall into a queue for approval by real persont that manage the site, and send that to the right category !

So if you know plugin or extension for joomla, drupal or wordpress that do that or another cms that will allow the flexibility to do that...

Dont tell me it's dangerous to let anybody upload photo, i can get porn, but it will be filter by human, and registering under false name do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's easily enough done in Drupal.

Set up standard drupal.  Get CCK, and the video modules necessary for how you want to handle video - filefield/imagefield is probably pretty close to what you need.

Set up the content types you want the users to be able to create.  Give the anonymous user role the create permissions for the types you want anonymous users to use.  Unset the published check box in the content type forms, so that new nodes will not be published.

I would then snag a copy of the workflow module, which will allow you to define states for the nodes to be in (such as 'waiting for review', 'approved', or 'rejected') and set up roles for your moderator(s) to review the content and approve.  Workflow's a pretty easy module to get working.

And there you go - anyone can create a new node, but the node won't be seen by visitors to the site until after it's been approved by a moderator.

A final thought - including a module like spam or mollom might work with preventing new nodes that are only spam from bothering your moderators.  Captcha might be helpful too, although that does get bypassed at times.